# AngularJS fill $scope.selected with object from <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with filling a scope with the correct data an keeping the correct attribute.

I've a small PHP script which returns an id, a name and a time as json array.

```
 {
  "times": [
    {
      "id": "myID",
      "name": "myName",
      "time": "40:00:00"
    },
    ...(10 more objects)
}
```

I want to create a dropdown element with the name as name and the id as value. I did this over a `ng-repeat` and this works very well.

```
<select name="StPl_Code" class="form-control" id="field-stpl-name" ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="i in times"  value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

My problem is, that I want to save the selected `i` in `$scope.selected` to use it's time value for an other input field without losing the value in the value attribute

Here is my angular code

```
  app.controller('auftraegeCrtl', function($scope, $http){
      $scope.selected = '';
      $http.get('index.php?page=times&json=true').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.times = data.times;
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      });
  });
```

Comment: Use ng-change on select element...https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: I thought there would be some working inline attributes instead of calling a function. I'll check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the ng-options directive, like this:

```
<select name="StPl_Code" class="form-control" id="field-stpl-name" ng-model="selected" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in times"></select>
```

You can see it working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2lwdwWMyx3V5J4foROKo?p=info)

Comment: I just found it         <select name="StPl_Code" class="form-control" id="field-stpl-name" ng-model="selected"  ng-options="item as item.name for item in times track by item.time">

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $scope.selected = {};
```

instead of :

```
 $scope.selected = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Ng-options' instead.

```
<select ng-options="i as i.name for i in times track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

This will set $scope.selected to the object selected